# Como definir a ordem em que os componentes receberão foco através do TAB?

Tags: java, swing

Para organizar a ordem de seleção de foco dos componentes até a versão 1.4 do java, utilizávamos o método [`setNextFocusableComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setNextFocusableComponent-java.awt.Component-). Porém ele foi descontinuado a partir da versão citada.

Gostaria de saber como faço nas versões mais recentes para poder controlar a ordem de foco de componentes na tela através da tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Por exemplo, o código abaixo tem 4 componentes distintos, e eles recebem foco na ordem que foram adicionados na tela:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class NextFocusTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField firstComp;
    private JComboBox<String> thirdComp;
    private JTextField secondComp;
    private JButton fourthComp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            NextFocusTest frame = new NextFocusTest();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public NextFocusTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20));
        this.panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 5));
        this.contentPane.add(this.panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.firstComp = new JTextField();
        this.firstComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        this.panel.add(this.firstComp);

        this.thirdComp = new JComboBox<String>();
        this.thirdComp.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] { "teste 1", "teste 2", "teste 3" }));
        this.thirdComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        this.panel.add(this.thirdComp);

        this.secondComp = new JTextField();
        this.secondComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        this.panel.add(this.secondComp);

        this.fourthComp = new JButton("OK");
        this.fourthComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 23));
        this.panel.add(this.fourthComp);

        pack();
    }
}
```

Alternando o foco com <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para definir manualmente a ordem de foco dos componentes, por exemplo, seguindo a ordem abaixo?

- primeiro campo de texto
- segundo campo de texto
- combobox
- botão

Comment: Já tentou usar o método `setNextFocusableComponent`. Veja um exemplo: `firstComp.setNextFocusableComponent(secondComp);`

Comment: @acklay logo no começo da pergunta eu cito ele, está descontinuado.

Comment: haha... só li o título. mals xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a classe [`FocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html) para definir a ordem de foco dos componentes de um `container`. Para tanto, extenda a classe `FocusTraversalPolicy`, implemente a política de foco e atribua utilizando `setFocusTraversalPolicy`. O código baseado no seu exemplo ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class NextFocusTest extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JPanel panel;
  private JTextField firstComp;
  private JComboBox<String> thirdComp;
  private JTextField secondComp;
  private JButton fourthComp;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      NextFocusTest frame = new NextFocusTest();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  public NextFocusTest() {
    initComponents();
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    this.contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(this.contentPane);

    this.panel = new JPanel();
    this.panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20));
    this.panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 5));
    this.contentPane.add(this.panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.firstComp = new JTextField();
    this.firstComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    this.panel.add(this.firstComp);

    this.thirdComp = new JComboBox<>();
    this.thirdComp.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[]{"teste 1", "teste 2", "teste 3"}));
    this.thirdComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    this.panel.add(this.thirdComp);

    this.secondComp = new JTextField();
    this.secondComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    this.panel.add(this.secondComp);

    this.fourthComp = new JButton("OK");
    this.fourthComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 23));
    this.panel.add(this.fourthComp);

    pack();
    setFocusTraversalPolicy(new PoliticaFoco());
  }

  class PoliticaFoco extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

    private final java.util.List<Component> componentes;
    private int focado = 0;

    public PoliticaFoco() {
      this.componentes = new LinkedList<>();
      this.componentes.add(thirdComp);
      this.componentes.add(firstComp);
      this.componentes.add(fourthComp);
      this.componentes.add(secondComp);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
      this.focado = (this.focado + 1) % this.componentes.size();

      return this.componentes.get(focado);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
      this.focado = (this.componentes.size() + this.focado - 1) % this.componentes.size();

      return this.componentes.get(focado);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
      return this.componentes.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
      return this.componentes.get(this.componentes.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
      return this.componentes.get(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Na implementação do `FocusTraversalPolicy`, implementamos os métodos `getComponentAfter`, `getComponentBefore`, `getDefaultComponent` e `getLastComponent` que determinam o componente que receberá o foco em cada uma das situações. Para controlar a ordem utilizei um `List` que recebe os componentes em ordem para controlar o foco. A desvantagem é que, para cada componente adicionado, será necessário incluir também na classe implementada.

---

Você pode também criar a política de foco genérica, da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class PoliticaFocoGenerica extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

  protected final java.util.List<Component> componentes = new LinkedList<>();
  private int focado = 0;

  @Override
  public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
    this.focado = (this.focado + 1) % this.componentes.size();

    return this.componentes.get(focado);
  }

  @Override
  public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
    this.focado = (this.componentes.size() + this.focado - 1) % this.componentes.size();

    return this.componentes.get(focado);
  }

  @Override
  public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
    return this.componentes.get(0);
  }

  @Override
  public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
    return this.componentes.get(this.componentes.size() - 1);
  }

  @Override
  public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
    return this.componentes.get(0);
  }
}
```

Apenas definindo os componentes em suas respectivas ordens, da seguinte forma:

```
class PoliticaFoco extends PoliticaFocoGenerica {

  public PoliticaFoco() {
    this.componentes.add(thirdComp);
    this.componentes.add(firstComp);
    this.componentes.add(fourthComp);
    this.componentes.add(secondComp);
  }
}
```

E no seu `container`:

```
...
setFocusTraversalPolicy(new PoliticaFoco());
...
```

Comment: Eu preciso mesmo criar uma classe a parte? Não tem algum método de container que eu possa definir isso não? Ou ser baseado no gerenciador de layout?

Comment: @Articuno negativo, depois da versão 1.4 este método foi descontinuado e substituído pelo `FocusTraversalPolicy`. Tem até um [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#intro) baseado nisso no site da `Oracle`

Comment: Entendi. Sem abusar demais, mas é possivel "generalizar" essa classe? Assim eu poderia reaproveitar em qualquer lugar sem ter que ficar copiando e adicionando os componentes na mao.

Comment: @Articuno Sim, coloquei um exemplo. Mas na realidade o componente você sempre vai ter que definir, afinal o objetivo é alterar a ordem manualmente, não?

Comment: No exemplo, você utilizou LinkedList. Essa escolha é opcional(posso escolher a lista de Collection que eu quiser) ou há alguma necessidade em se utilizar esta especificamente?

Comment: @Articuno é opcional, inclusive no exemplo do tutorial da Oracle é utilizado um `array` simples. Utilizei o `List` por julgar a implementação mais fácil de compreender

Comment: Deu certo! Preferi criar um construtor na classe de politica de foco, pra ela receber de cara uma lista de componentes. Obrigado :)

Comment: @Articuno bem interessante fazer dessa forma, fica mais "fechado", evitando erros posteriores!