# Entrar em modo de edição ao digitar algo quando a célula da JTable estiver com foco

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho um `celleditor` em formato de `textarea`, e quando está com foco, eu aperto alguma palavra pra digitar na `celula`. Ele abre o modo edição, mas não escreve nada, o que pode estar errado?

classe funcionario

```
package javaapplication10;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */
public class Funcionario {

    private String nome;

    public Funcionario(String nome, int idade, int matricula) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

classe FuncionarioTableModel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class FuncionarioTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String colunas[] = {"nome"};
    private ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios;
    private final int COLUNA_NOME = 0;


    public FuncionarioTableModel(ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return funcionarios.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int indice) {
        return colunas[indice];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return String.class;
                        default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Funcionario funcionario = this.funcionarios.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return funcionario.getNome();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Funcionario funcionario = this.funcionarios.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                funcionario.setNome(String.valueOf(aValue));
                break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

classe JtableExemple

```
package javaapplication10;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTableExample extends JFrame {

    private JTable tabela;
    private JScrollPane scrollPainel;

    public JTableExample() {
        renderizarTela();
    }

    private void renderizarTela() {


    Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario("",0,0);
    Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario("", 0, 0);
    Funcionario f3 = new Funcionario("", 0, 0);
    Funcionario f4 = new Funcionario("", 0, 0);

        ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
        funcionarios.add(f1);
        funcionarios.add(f2);
        funcionarios.add(f3);
        funcionarios.add(f4);

        FuncionarioTableModel model = new FuncionarioTableModel(funcionarios);

        this.tabela = new JTable(model);
        this.scrollPainel = new JScrollPane(tabela);
        tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new TextAreaEditor());
                tabela.setRowHeight(50);
        this.add(scrollPainel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JTableExample tb = new JTableExample();
                tb.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                tb.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

// celleditor
    class TextAreaEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

        protected JScrollPane scrollpane;
        protected JTextArea textarea;

        public TextAreaEditor() {
            super(new JCheckBox());
            scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
            textarea = new JTextArea();
            textarea.setLineWrap(true);
            textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
//            textarea.setBorder(new TitledBorder("This is a JTextArea"));
            scrollpane.getViewport().add(textarea);

            // colocar para editar em 2 click
            setClickCountToStart(2);
            //
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            textarea.setText((String) value);

            return scrollpane;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return textarea.getText();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Seu código funcionou normalmente aqui

Comment: Perdão a demora Articuno! Quando ele está com foco em cima da célula e tento digitar alguma escrita ou numero, ele abre a edição, mas não digita. Caso eu dê dois clique ele digita. Nesse caso eu precisava q quando digitasse algo ele já ativasse a edição sem dar os dois clique

Comment: Remova a linha que você adicionou pra entrar na edição com dois cliques então.

Comment: No caso eu preciso de ter ela também.. tem que ter as duas opções. Mas o estranho é igual disse, quando estar com foco, tentar digitar alguma coisa e mesmo assim não digitar.

Comment: Cara você ta fazendo errado esse celleditor. Repare que você passa um JCheckbox no construtor mas depois retorna um JScrollpane. Se for pra usar componentes que não seja um campo de texto, um combo ou um checkbox, você não pode usar defaultcelleditor, você precisa implementar do zero um celleditor. Sua classe `TextAreaEditor` precisa ser refeita do zero, dessa forma ela jamais vai funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Bom Articuno, eu não entendo muito.. O Scroll coloquei para que quando acabar de digitar e a escrita não couber na célula, ele aumenta a célula automaticamente. ja esse checkbox não faço ideia. poderia me da uma mão pra limpar isso? Agradeço muito

Comment: Fiz um modelo mas tem um problema, como você pretende encerrar a edição no campo? Enter não funciona na textArea, ele quebra linha.

Comment: Era bom com Tab, mas tab também não funciona neh?

Comment: Consegui fazer, mas sem dois cliques no campo, ele abre direto para edição.

Comment: com os 2 cliques não é possível?

Comment: geralmente o pessoal sempre clica em outra celula para perder o foco e pode dar tab e nesse caso já vai abrir outro campo

Comment: É possível, mas não compensa o trabalho. Você terá que escolher, se for com dois cliques, não posso ajudar porque teria que reescrever muita coisa e pra algo tão simples eu acho que não vale a trabalheira.

Comment: Entendi, pode ser da maneira q vc disse

Comment: Acredito q vá atender sim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua classe `TextAreaEditor` está herdando de [`DefaultCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html), e como a grande maioria das classes `DefaultXXX` da api do swing, elas são somente para funcionalidades básicas a componentes, de modo a permitir implementar essas funcionalidades sem ter que reescrever do zero. Como no caso da classe citada, ela permite alterar o editor padrão de células editáveis(que é um campo de texto) para outros componentes básicos, como `JCheckBox`,  `JComboBox` ou o próprio `JTextField` com alguma possibilidade de personalização. Não é a toa que se você acessar a documentação, verá que essa classe só tem 3 construtores específicos, que esperam justamente um dos 3 componentes citados.

Não sei se foi uma tentativa proposital de contornar a restrição da classe ou apenas desconhecimento, mas no construtor da classe `TextAreaEditor` você faz:

```
public TextAreaEditor() {
    super(new JCheckBox());

...
```

Com isso, você indica ao `DefaultCellEditor` que o editor padrão será um checkbox, mas depois tenta passar um `JScrollPane`. Isso tem tudo para dar errado, como pode ser visto no seu próprio exemplo.

O recomendado para casos onde você precisa implementar um editor diferente dos suportados pelo `DefaultCellEditor` é escrever um editor que estenda de [`AbstractCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractCellEditor.html), classe que possui algumas implementações padrões que permite escrever um *CellEditor* com outros componentes, e também precisa implementar [`TableCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html), para tornar a classe compatível com a tabela.

Levando em consideração o que você já tinha feito na sua classe, fiz essa:

```
public class TextAreaEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scroll;

    public TextAreaEditor() {

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setBorder(new TitledBorder("This is a JTextArea"));

        // altera o comportamento padrao do TAB para que transfira o foco
        // neste caso, vai transferir para a celular seguinte
        textArea.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "transferFocus");

        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int rowIndex,
            int colIndex) {
        
        String text = value == null ? "" : value.toString();
        textArea.setText(text);

        return scroll;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return textArea.getText();
    }
}
```

Apesar de estar comentado, vale ressaltar a linha abaixo:

```
textArea.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "transferFocus");
```

Pelo fato de estarmos criando um editor de células personalizado para a tabela, é necessário também definirmos uma forma de encerrar a edição. Normalmente bastaria adicionar um `KeyListener` ao editor e, ao detectar <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, invocar o método [`stopCellEditing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#stopCellEditing--), mas como se trata de uma `JTextArea`, que é um campo multilinhas, espera-se que seja possível escrever textos multilinhas, e capturando o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> tiraríamos essa característica do componente.

A linha acima remapeia a função do <kbd>TAB</kbd>, que por padrão dentro de uma textArea salta 4 espaços a frente(como ocorre na maioria dos editores de texto), e configura a tecla para que transfira o foco do editor para o componente seguinte.

> Poderíamos também organizar o foco, mas isso é mais complexo e foge totalmente da dúvida inicial. Se quiser ler mais sobre foco, pode ler na documentação o tutorial de [Como usar o subsistema de foco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) e também [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236205/28595) aqui no site.

Aplicando a classe acima como editor da coluna ou da tabela inteira, já teremos células com uma *textarea* como editor, mas como o objetivo é permitir também que entre em modo edição quando se inicie digitação, é preciso alterar um comportamento da tabela, para que redirecione corretamente o foco a área de texto. A forma mais simples que encontrei de fazer isso foi alterando o método [`changeSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#changeSelection-int-int-boolean-boolean-):

```
this.tabela = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend) {

        //inicia a edicao na celula da tabela
        //e quando o editor for o scrollpane, transfere
        //o foco para a textarea dentro dela
        if(editCellAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)) {
            Component editor = getEditorComponent();

            if(editor instanceof JScrollPane)
            ((JScrollPane)editor).getViewport().getView().requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        super.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex, toggle, extend);
    }
};
```

Ao alterar a seleção na tabela, este método é chamado, e nele, eu verifico se a célula atual é editável e inicio o modo de edição, através do método [`editCellAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editCellAt-int-int-). Caso seja, verifico se o editor é um `JScrollPane`, que é o que nos interessa, e quando for, faço com que o foco seja transferido para o componente inserido nele, no nosso caso será a própria `JTextArea`.

Com isso, o campo já abre em modo de edição, seja clicando nele ou alternando com TAB. Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Extra

O texto anterior já responde a pergunta, mas o fato de colocar um editor personalizado na tabela também te força a escrever uma forma de como a tabela renderizará a informação daquela célula. Se você não escrever um *renderer*, todo o texto será exibido em uma unica linha, pois o *renderer* padrão de célula(assim como editor padrão) é um campo de texto simples.

Como já tinha um exemplo pronto e tive que usar para testar os códigos da resposta, segue o renderer para o editor acima, com algumas adaptações para exibição correta de textos multilinhas(trechos relevantes comentados):

```
class TextAreaCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {

    public TextAreaCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        
        
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        
        // ajusta o tamanho da celular conforme o texto digitado
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(), getPreferredSize().height);
        //ajusta o tamanho da linha da celula, conforme o texto digitado
        //para evitar que o texto seja cortado pela altura da linha
        if (table.getRowHeight(row) < getPreferredSize().height) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Basta aplicar a mesma coluna do editor:

```
tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaCellRenderer());
```

Além de suportar texto multilinhas, a tabela também renderizará corretamente o texto. Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que você pode adicionar uma borda no renderer e diminuir a fonte se for desejável assim, mas isso fica por sua conta. :D

Comment: Nossa @Articuno, não esperava por tudo isso cara.. Você ganhou uma nota 1000 por esse trabalho imenso. Só tenho que te agradecer por tudo que fez. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Quer cobrar por umas aulas particulares não? :D

Comment: @Articuno parabéns pela excelente resposta :D