# Como disparar um método ao terminar de editar uma coluna do tipo Inteiro na JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Preciso chamar um método que mostre para o usuário uma mensagem qualquer.

Este método deve ser chamado no exato momento em que o usuário terminar de editar uma coluna da JTable do tipo Inteiro e o usuário não tiver digitado um número inteiro.

Ou seja, o método deve ser chamado no momento em que a coluna ficar 'vermelha'.

Abaixo vou colocar  uma imagem de exemplo que o articuno usou em um de  seus posts, apenas para  exemplificar quando o evento devera ser chamado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está o código que  estou desenvolvendo.

```
 public class Dados {
        /**
         * @return the coluna0
         */
        public String getColuna0() {
            return coluna0;
        }
        /**
         * @param coluna0 the coluna0 to set
         */
        public void setColuna0(String coluna0) {
            this.coluna0 = coluna0;
        }
        /**
         * @return the colunaInteiro
         */
        public Integer getColunaInteiro() {
            return colunaInteiro;
        }
        /**
         * @param colunaInteiro the colunaInteiro to set
         */
        public void setColunaInteiro(Integer colunaInteiro) {
            this.colunaInteiro = colunaInteiro;
        }
        private String coluna0;
        private Integer colunaInteiro;
    }
```

.

```
public class TesteTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String colunas[] = {"Coluna0", "colunaInteiro"};
    private List<Dados> dados;
    private final int COLUNA_0 = 0;
    private final int COLUNA_INTEIRO = 1;

    public TesteTableModel(List<Dados> dados) {
        this.dados = dados;
    }

    //retorna se a célula é editável ou não
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    //retorna o total de itens(que virarão linhas) da nossa lista
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    //retorna o total de colunas da tabela
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    //retorna o nome da coluna de acordo com seu indice
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int indice) {
        return colunas[indice];
    }

    //determina o tipo de dado da coluna conforme seu indice
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_0:
                return String.class;
            case COLUNA_INTEIRO:
                return Integer.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }
    //preenche cada célula da tabela
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Dados dados = this.dados.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_0:
                return dados.getColuna0();
            case COLUNA_INTEIRO:
                return dados.getColunaInteiro();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class GuiPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;
    List<Dados> dados = new ArrayList<Dados>();

    public GuiPrincipal(JTable table) throws HeadlessException {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void addDadosInDados() {
        Dados dado = new Dados();
        dado.setColuna0("Dado qualquer");
        dado.setColunaInteiro(1);
        dados.add(dado);
    }

    public GuiPrincipal() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Exemplo JTable");
        addDadosInDados();// add dados em dados       
        table = new JTable(new TesteTableModel(dados));
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    // este é o método onde é executado nosso programa
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuiPrincipal gui = new GuiPrincipal();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Como faço para disparar um método neste exato momento?

Comment: Vinicius, esse código não é compilavel. Teste-o e verifique o erro, para que seja possivel testarmos.

Comment: Na verdade o código funciona  acabei de  testar, só não estava separado as classes  na pergunta e sem o "package com o local do arquivo em cada uma", alterei e vou testar o código de resposta.

Comment: Só funciona na sua IDE. Colei todas as classes separadamente e o código não compila, pois há metodos ausentes na classe Dados. Por isso que você deve criar um projeto separado quando estiver criando um **[mcve]**.

Comment: Vinicius, voce alterou a duvida pra algo completamente diferente, por isso, reverti a pergunta. Por isso é importante fornecer um código executavel, para que as respostas sejam de acordo com a pergunta.

Comment: Eu peguei o mesmo código e coloquei em uma aplicação totalmente nova, fiz o teste no IDE NetBeans e na IDE InteliJ. Em ambos o código rodou. Quais métodos não funcionaram quando você testou?  Como você fez para rodar o código, se você me disser tento executalo da mesma forma e assim corrigir estes erros.

Comment: Repare bem no uso da classe Dado dentro do GuiPrincipal. Você está chamando o metodo add, que nao existe nesta classe. De qualquer forma, as soluções possiveis estão na resposta, há duas formas, se uma não servir, com certeza a outra servirá, pois não há outras formas.

Comment: O Add do jFrame? De qualquer forma , nao era bem essa a pergunta.

Comment: Vinicius, as formas de se fazer o que voce quer estão na resposta, peço que leia novamente, pois eu sugeri 2 formas diferentes, não apenas a que você utilizou primeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente aplicar umas das formas sugeridas abaixo:

## 1 - Utilizando [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)

É possível monitorar quando houver alguma edição de célula na tabela, adicionando um [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) a ela, filtrando apenas quando houver notificação de listeners de edição de células:

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener(e -> {
    
    if("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
        if(!table.isEditing())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"fim da edição em alguma celula");
    }
});
```

Um problema dessa forma é que entrará na condicional sempre que qualquer célula da tabela sair do modo de edição.

---

## 2 - Utilizando um [`TableCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html)

Esta forma é um pouco mais complicada, pois em situações onde se tem um tipo especifico de dados na coluna, pode ser necessário a criação de um `TableCellEditor` próprio, como pode ser visto [neste exemplo de outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274563/28595), mas para simplificar a demonstração, utilizei a classe `DefaultTableCellEditor`.

```
class ShowMessageCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{

    public ShowMessageCellEditor(JTextField textField) {
        super(textField);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "celula modificada");
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }
}
```

E para aplicar na coluna específica:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new ShowMessageCellEditor(new JTextField()));
```

No método `getColumn(index)` você deve passar o índice da coluna da tabela que quer que ocorra a ação ao terminar a edição. Lembre-se que índices em java iniciam em 0 e não 1.

As colunas de uma `JTable` utilizam editores que implementam a interface `CellEditor`, e essa interface possui o método [`stopCellEditing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#stopCellEditing--), que detecta quando a edição na célula foi interrompida, e aceita a alteração realizada, mesmo que seja parcial, notificando em seguida todos os *ouvintes* de que aquela célula não está mais em modo de edição.

Anteriormente, a versão estava utilizando `fireEditingStopped()`, mas a função deste método é apenas notificar *ouvintes* do evento ocorrido, é dentro do `stopCellEditing()` que você deve disparar seu método.

---

**Referencias:**

- [SWING JTable, cell start to edit event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41266365/5524514)
- [Concepts: Editors and Renderers(tutorial oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: Eu ainda desenvolvo em um source que não suporta "lambda expressions".  Vou buscar como se  converte.

Comment: @ViniciusSilva não seja por isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595

Comment: Está correto. Após analisar com calma sua resposta consegui chegar ao resultado esperado usando a solução numero 2.